# Program throws Stack Overflow Error

Tags: java, exception, stack-overflow

The following program compiles correctly. What is causing the Stack Overflow Error? How is the exception pushed on to the stack?

```
public class Reluctant {

    private Reluctant internalInstance = new Reluctant();

    public Reluctant() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("I’m not coming out");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Reluctant b = new Reluctant();
            System.out.println("Surprise!");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("I told you so");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a field initialization code which is automatically added to the constructor body by javac compiler. Effectively your constructor looks like this:

```
private Reluctant internalInstance;

public Reluctant() throws Exception {
    internalInstance = new Reluctant();
    throw new Exception("I’m not coming out");
}
```

So it calls itself recursively.

Comment: just know this, your answer helps!

Comment: Didn't know the field initialization moves to constructor. So, if its the first becomes statement like you mentioned. The exception is never thrown. Thanks to recursion.

Comment: @Sorter: and if you have multiple constructors, the same field initialization code is added to every single constructor (just after superclass initialization, but before actual constructor body).

Answer (score 4):

This line in your `main` method results in infinite recursion:

```
Reluctant b = new Reluctant();
```

Every time you try to create an instance of `Reluctant`, the first thing you do is create another instance, which creates another instance, which creates another instance, which... You get the idea.

Voila, stack overflow!

Comment: That's the line where the recursion starts.

Answer (score 2):

You have an infinite loop. Every instance of `Reluctant` class instantiates another `Reluctant` object on `internalInstance` declaration. So, when you instantiate the first `Reluctant` object on your `main` method, the program creates one instance after another, over and over again, till the stack overflows.

Replace this line.-

```
private Reluctant internalInstance = new Reluctant();
```

for

```
private Reluctant internalInstance;
```

Comment: Well explained the recursion process.